# Use standard css class inside css module

Tags: css, sass, react-css-modules

i'm styling a React component with css modules.
there's a part where i insert html code using  `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
<div className={styles.article_text} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.text}} />
```

i have no control over this html code but i want to style it. i can style the html by using tag rules like this:

```
.article_text {
  h2 {
    @apply text-3xl mt-6 mb-4; /* this is applied to headings ... */
  }

  p {
    @apply mb-3; /* and paragraphs */
  }
  ...
```

what's not working is styling css classes this way:

```
.article_text {
  .listblock {
    @apply bg-white; /* this doesnt apply to the div.listblock inside the html code*/
  }
```

is there a way i can get this to work?